# React native - post raw text data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to send this type data in raw text format using react native. please help-

submit Qsubmit_form=1&form_noresubmit_code=1525265560&question=OKKKK NEW APPP&submit=

Answer (score 3):

You can use fetch API for both GET and POST requests. Example of POST request:

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

You can check out official docs for networking [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Comment: What if you can't send a json?